# If $0<p\leq|a_n|\leq q$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, find the radius of convergence f $\sum a_nx^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $0<p\leq|a_n|\leq q$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, find the radius of convergence f $$\sum a_nx^n$$.
For this one thing i could conclude that the series is bounded in a compact domain but convergence made me confused. what is the answer?

Comment: Have you heard of the Cauchy-Hadamard formula for the radius of convergence?

Comment: @DanielFischer No.

Comment: Okay. Then apply the root test.

Comment: For the unknown $a_n$ how can we? but i will try.

Answer (score 2):

If $x>1$: 
$|a_n|x^n \ge px^n\to\infty$: $R\le 1$.

if $x<1$:
$|a_n|x^n \le qx^n, \sum qx^n < \infty$ hence $R\ge 1$.

Comment: How you are predicting this. Is this true when the nth term goes to infinity $R\leq 1$?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are intended to convey... :O

Comment: i use the definition: $R = \sup \{ x \in \Bbb R^+ : \sum |a_n|x^n<\infty\}$

Answer (score 0):

As you are not aware of Cauchy-Hadamard formula for the radius of convergence let us see this as some geometric series...

See $\sum a_nx^n$ as $\sum (\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}x)^n$. For this to converge,  you need

> $|\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}x|<1\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ i.e., $|x|<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$

You have :
$$0<p\leq|a_n|\leq q\Rightarrow 0<\sqrt[n]{p}\leq \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq \sqrt[n]{q}\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}<???$$

Can you conclude now?